# how to apply CSSClass & style in while create asp button using StringBuilder in c#

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, class, stringbuilder

My Code is below which is not working for applied css for created control at client side when applying it,
 
my css class is : **img-rounded**

```
string strClass = "img-rounded", strColor="Green";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<asp:Button OnClick=\"Button1_Click\" runat=\"server\" ID=\"Btn1\" CssClass=\"" + strClass + "\"  BackColor=\"" + strColor + "\">" + cellData + "</asp:Button><br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot add a `<asp:Button` as a string to the page and expect it to work. If you want to add true asp buttons dynamically you have to take a different approach:

```
        Button button = new Button();
        button.CssClass = strClass;
        button.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        button.ID = "Btn1";
        button.Text = cellData;
        button.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(button);
```

Or you could still add a "normal" HTML button to the page, but then you have to use `class=` instead of `CssClass=`, which is an attribute of most asp controls (just as `BackColor`).

```
sb.Append("<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"Button1_Click()\" id=\"Btn1\" class=\"" + strClass + "\" value=\"" + cellData + "\"><br />");
```

Note that the `OnClick` is now a javascript call with `()` at the end. Of course it will not fire an event in code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Manish that is not how you add an asp button, this article explains how to do it. http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamic-Controls-Made-Easy-in-ASP.Net.aspx
Once you create the button in the code behind then you can access all its properties including cssclass.